inverted rows,cols in cv.resize
I don't understand why the np.shape passed to cv.resize needs me to swap the tuple elements:

  # Our operations on the frame come here
  gray = cv.cvtColor(frame, cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
  # Display the resulting frame
  cv.imshow('frame', gray)

  (rows, cols) = np.shape(gray)
  
  resized = cv.resize(gray, (cols * 2, rows * 2))
  cv.imshow('resized', resized)



The second parameter of cv.resize is the Python equivalent of cv::Size whose constructor takes first width and then height (this is represented as a tuple (width, height)). However, the standard way of representing images in memory is in row-major order, so shape gives you (height, width).

Numpy always produces rows, cols. But OpenCV always wants cols, rows.

Thanks for the hints, clearly cv.Size it's not a np.shape... sorry for the noise, if someone cares about converting in an answer, I will accept it...
